# Opendaylight : One of the rest calls out of many returing 401 error everytime

Tags: java, rest, opendaylight

I am making rest calls to opendaylight.
Suppose i make 15 calls simultaneously using a for loop(each call is handeled by a seperate thread), then one or two of them always result in 401 status code.

I dont want that to happen.
Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a bug.  ODL is an opensource project with an active community and you  will get a better response  there than on stackoverflow.

I suggest that you retry  using the helium release http://www.opendaylight.org/software  and report it on https://bugs.opendaylight.org/ in the controller project.  You will need to register.

There is not enough information here to investigate so when you write the bug report please provide:

- Software build used:
  Needed for quick turn-around of ‘probably fixed’ issues
- Environment used:
  To diagnose potential environment problems:
- Any customization outside of project-wide baseline
  To understand deviations, helps prioritizing ‘currently unsupported’ issues
- Description of steps taken:
  Needed for reproduction, helps finding ‘you are doing it wrong’ issues, here you need to describe the API call used
- Description of expected result:
  E.g. what the reporter thinks should happen, helps finding ‘not-a-bug’ and architecture/design issues
- Description of actual result:
  E.g. what actually happened
- Reasonable amount of logs